# cant understand what is happening in a section of FOREACH loop PHP

Tags: php

So I have used some code recently and I would like to know how it works completely because I am not a fan of using stuff I don't understand and where I got the code did not show how it worked. What it does is append all the checked checkboxes to the variable $information.

here is the code I used, the submitted form and the php script

```
<form name="checkboxform" action="" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="ninjas[]" value="stuff">stuff<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="ninjas[]" value="more stuff">more stuff<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

so when i click submit this function runs

```
//excuse the ninja naming part, needed to have a laugh cause this was so frustrating :)
function sneakyNinjas() {
$array = $_POST['ninjas'];
$information = "";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $information .= $value; 
}
```

So I get that it loops through each value in the array and that is why I have named them as such.
 But the **$keys =>$value** part is what I don't understand.
 How does it determine when the checkbox has been clicked? 
Does it use a boolean that is sent with the array?
any help in understanding the process would be greatly appreciated or a link so I can read up on it cause I have found nothing so far, and by all means correct me where I am wrong with anything I said.

Comment: $_POST is an associative array. I should only be giving you the value where the key is 'ninjas'.

Comment: tip: you could just use `foreach ($_POST['ninjas'] as $value){` ...; your not using the $key and you don't need to create a new variable $array

Comment: sweet, that was my next question. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an HTML form is submitted, only the values for checkboxes that have been checked are submitted. Unchecked or disabled checkboxes are omitted so your array only contains checked values.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an associative array. It should only be giving you the value where the key is 'ninjas'.

Comment: `If "ninjas" is your check box, it will have a true or false value.` - incorrect: if you check the box, it will have the value you specify, or "on" by default, otherwise it wont exist at all in the post array

Comment: Good to know. I prob. use empty() too much. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that only checked checkboxes are passed when submitting a form. In your loop, the $key is the field name passed and the $value is its value (matching the attributes in you HTML). The unchecked fields shouldn't be there at all (if I remember correctly).

Comment: That would be true if he were looping the `$_POST` array, but since he's looping `$_POST['ninjas']` the `$key` will be a numeric index of the array - not overly useful in this situation